# Expected ctor

Tags: c++

I am writing a delete member function for a Binary Search Tree. I have already written a boolean search function to return true/false based on whether it is in the BST. I have retooled it as a new function to return a Node* so that my delete function can call it and get a pointer directly to the correct Node.

Right now, I am getting a compile error on this line of code:

```
//"Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
Node* BinarySearchTree::Search(int val);
```

struct Node is private to BinarySearchTree. I tried adding them as friends to each other, but that did not resolve the problem. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Is this declaration inside the class, or outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should qualify `Node`:

```
BinarySearchTree::Node* BinarySearchTree::Search(int val);
```